# unable to login in openldap

Tags: openldap, activiti

I have integrated openldap with activiti-explorer and activiti-rest. I am using activiti 5.19.0 and openldap 2.4.31. I am using activiti-rest api for accessing activiti rest services and authentication process in activiti is via openldap. when i am accessing activiti-rest services, then it is opening number of connection for openldap. After sometime, i am not able to login in activiti and openldap as well. It is showing error "TCP cannot open /etc/hosts.allow and /etc/hosts.deny" in openldap error logs.

Please give any solution for this.
Thanks

Comment: I'm guessing that your open file descriptors of your system have been used up. If on linux for example, you can use the ulimit command to change the max number of open file descriptors.

Comment: I have used ulimit -n 4096 to increase the limit of open file descriptors. But when i reboot the server, it is again reset to 1024.

Answer (score 0):

A couple of things to try.
First check your ulimit for open file descriptors:

```
ulimit -n
```

Next, check how many files openldap is holding onto:

```
ls /proc/`cat slapd.pid`/fd | wc
```

As Joram indicated in his comment, likely you are simply running out of available file descriptors.

Comment: ulimit for open file descriptors is 1024. when i run second command specified by you, it is showing error:  cat: slapd.pid: No such file or directory
ls: cannot access /proc//fd: No such file or directory
      0       0       0